# css not working background hover active - not syntax issue

Tags: css, syntax, hover

Hello i really try to search and to do mutiple experiments, anyway i can get this working..

Im using a javascript menu, working Perfect, but i try to change the background for each menu, it also go great.. but the HOVER and ACTIVE, are not working for that elements, why.. this code must do it or that was what i think.. =( pls help me learn.

css code

```
/* COMIENZA  TOP NAVI*/
 .topnavi a {
    width:90px;
    height:65px;
    float:left;
    margin:3px;
    background:url(../imagenes/topnav_01.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    display:block;
    font-size:1px;
}


#tn02 {background:url(../imagenes/topnav_02.png) 0 0 no-repeat;}     
#tn03 {background:url(../imagenes/topnav_03.png) 0 0 no-repeat;}
#tn04 {background:url(../imagenes/topnav_04.png) 0 0 no-repeat;}
#tn05 {background:url(../imagenes/topnav_05.png) 0 0 no-repeat;}




/* mouseover state */
.topnavi a:hover {
    background-position:0 -65px;
}

/* active state (current page state) */
.topnavi a.active {
    background-position:0 -130px;
}        

/* TERMINA TOP NAVI*/
```

html code

```
<div class="topnavi">
  <a href="1" class="active" id="tn01"/>
  <a href="2" class="" id="tn02"/>
  <a href="3" class="" id="tn03"/>
  <a href="4" class="" id="tn04"/>
  <a href="5" class="" id="tn05"/>
</div>
```

Comment: /* active state (current page state) */ - This is wrong. The Active pseudo selector does not do what you think it does. - http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-active

Comment: Check his markup. The active item has a class of `active`. It's not a style for when the link is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID references take preference over class references. Don't forget that the "C" in CSS stands for Cascading! Your `#tn0*` rules are taking precendence over the `background-position` property you define later.Try adding `!important`.

```
/* mouseover state */
.topnavi a:hover {
    background-position:0 -65px !important;
}

/* active state (current page state) */
.topnavi a.active {
    background-position:0 -130px !important;
}
```